# AppDelegate Issues When Running App on Device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, appdelegate

I have an app that has a simple timer that runs on an animated viewcontroller using SpriteKit. I want the timer to continue so I used the Notification Center and posted notifications in the AppDelegate as follows:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("stopTimerNotification", object: nil)
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("stopTimerNotification", object: nil)    
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("startTimerNotification", object: nil)      
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("startTimerNotification", object: nil)


}
```

My timer runs fine on the device when connected to Xcode and also runs fine on device when the "Sleep Time" app is running on device (and not connected to Xcode). I've searched but cannot fathom this one out. Any suggestions?

The code that executes when both NSNotifications are called is:

```
func stopTimerInBackground(note: NSNotification) {

    if(isRunningStopwatch == true) {

   stopPressed()

    stopTimerInBackgroundDate = NSDate()



    }

}

func startTimerInBackground(note: NSNotification) {


    var restartTimerInBackgroundDate:NSDate! = NSDate()

    if (isStopwatch == true) {

    previousElapsedTime = restartTimerInBackgroundDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(stopTimerInBackgroundDate)

    previousElapsedTime = 0

    startPressed()

    }

}
```

I just wonder if it's a plist value I have to change?

Comment: Sorry but I not understood your question, can you be more specific about the problem please? Anyway your time will receive "startTimerNotification" twice with this approach, you need to use only two of four states you had used.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jan. When I run the app on my iPhone, the app runs as it should if the "sleep time" app by Azumio is running. I can only think that the sleep time app keeps services running on my iPhone that my app requires to run the timer properly. I don't know what those services could be.

Comment: Can you show the code that actions the NSNotifications?

Comment: Sure Paul, I will edit my question.